# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre restart y deploy: restart en docker-compose v.3?

Tags: docker-compose

Entiendo que a partir de la versión 3 de docker-compose es posible utilizar las políticas de restart con más parámetros de la siguiente forma:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
```

Sin embargo, en muchos ejemplos, acá y en otros foros, siguen mostrando la siguiente forma:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    restart: on-failure [3]
```

¿Es posible hacerlo de las dos formas a partir de la versión 3?

En la documentación no queda claro.

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación afirma que lo que se declare en "deploy" es ignorado por "docker-compose up" y "docker-compose run". En este caso, utilizo "docker-compose up -d", por lo que entiendo debo declararlo de la siguiente forma

```
version: "3"
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    restart: on-failure [3]
```

Ambas formas son válidas, pero depende de cómo se ejecute el docker-compose, ¿esa es la diferencia?

Answer (score 0):

Realicé las pruebas y sucede exactamente lo que mencioné en la respuesta anterior,  deploy es ignorado por 'docker-compose':

```
WARNING: Some services (app, db) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored.
Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to
deploy to a swarm.
```

En conclusión, la forma correcta para 'docker-compose' es:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    restart: on-failure [3]
```